# How to display sqlites file.db in eclipe as part of python 3

Tags: python, eclipse, sqlite

I'm trying to add the below code, which seems to get added, but when I go to view the database.db file, it outputs just like the image, could anyone explain how would I get the proper output from eclipse? I'm using the latest python which has sqlite3 included.

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
db.execute('create table person (firstname text, secondname text, age int)')
```

[image: After Adding Data, and trying to display it, it comes out like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to view the .db file, If that's the case use this to view the db.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/